# Xamarin.Forms: Putting A Label Inside A BarChart Layout

Tags: xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I am using oxyplot to plot a bar chart. I wish to add an extra label in the chart. I've tried to use Textannotation but it's not showing on the chart. What is the mistake I'm making to cause the text not to appear, is it the DataPoint? Please help.

```
plotModel = new PlotModel
            {
                Title = "Daily",
                LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Outside,
                LegendPosition = LegendPosition.BottomCenter,
                LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Horizontal,
                LegendBorderThickness = 0
            };

            TextAnnotation txtlabel = new TextAnnotation();
            txtlabel.Text = "Test";
            txtlabel.TextColor = OxyColors.Red;
            txtlabel.Stroke = OxyColors.Red;
            txtlabel.StrokeThickness = 5;
            txtlabel.FontSize = 36;
            txtlabel.TextPosition = new DataPoint(21, 3.5);

            plotModel.Annotations.Add(txtlabel);

            string sPrevType = "";
            string sCurrentType = "";
            DateTime dtdate;

            var sr = new ColumnSeries();
            var col = new ColumnItem();
            int iCount = 0;
            List<decimal> lstI = new List<decimal>();
            List<decimal> lstD = new List<decimal>();
            List<decimal> lstS = new List<decimal>();

            foreach (var itm in _dateodr)
            {
                dtdate = itm.date;
                sCurrentType = itm.Type;
                lstI.Add(itm.I_Unit);
                lstD.Add(itm.D_Unit);
                lstS.Add(itm.S_Unit);
                if (sCurrentType != sPrevType && sPrevType != "")
                {
                    sr = new ColumnSeries();
                    sr.Title = sPrevType;
                    sr.LabelPlacement = LabelPlacement.Outside;
                    sr.StrokeColor = OxyColors.Black;
                    sr.StrokeThickness = 1;
                    //sr.LabelFormatString = "{0:#,##0.00}";
                    plotModel.Series.Add(sr);

                }
                sPrevType = sCurrentType;
                iCount += 1;
            }

            if (iCount == _dateodr.Count)
            {
                sr = new ColumnSeries();
                sr.Title = sPrevType;
                sr.LabelPlacement = LabelPlacement.Outside;
                sr.StrokeColor = OxyColors.Black;
                sr.StrokeThickness = 1;
                //sr.LabelFormatString = "{0:#,##0.00}";
                sr.FontSize = 10;
                plotModel.Series.Add(sr);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
            {
                ColumnSeries ssr = (ColumnSeries)plotModel.Series[i];
                var colIm = new ColumnItem();
                colIitm.Value = double.Parse(lstI[i].ToString()) / 1000;
                ssr.Items.Add(colIitm);

                var colDOitm = new ColumnItem();
                colDitm.Value = double.Parse(lstD[i].ToString()) / 1000;
                ssr.Items.Add(colDitm);

                var colSitm = new ColumnItem();
                colSitm.Value = double.Parse(lstS[i].ToString()) / 1000;
                ssr.Items.Add(colSitm);

            }


            categoryaxis.Labels.Add("I");
            categoryaxis.Labels.Add("Dr");
            categoryaxis.Labels.Add("Sr");


            switch (sUnitType)
            {
                case "2":
                    valueAxis = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, MinimumPadding = 0, MaximumPadding = 0.06, AbsoluteMinimum = 0, Title = "m", Angle = 90, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, FontSize = 15 };
                    break;

                case "qy":
                    valueAxis = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, MinimumPadding = 0, MaximumPadding = 0.06, AbsoluteMinimum = 0, Title = "Qy", Angle = 90, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, FontSize = 15 };
                    break;

                case "Am":
                    valueAxis = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, MinimumPadding = 0, MaximumPadding = 0.06, AbsoluteMinimum = 0, Title = "Am", Angle = 90, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, FontSize = 15 };
                    break;
            }

            plotModel.Axes.Add(categoryaxis);
            plotModel.Axes.Add(valueAxis);

        }


        PlotView plot = new PlotView
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            Model = plotModel
        };


        Content = plot;
```

Comment: I answered a similar question, see if it helps you [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636886/xamarin-forms-putting-a-label-inside-a-piechart-layout/38683231#38683231).

Comment: Hi jstreet, i tried but it not show up.  I not try the data point but no luck.

Comment: Try placing the annotation in a data point that is within the existing points in your X and Y axes.

Comment: Hi jstreet, how I can put the data point within the X and Y axes?

Comment: I assume you know the X and Y values you're loading in your chart, right? So, for the purposes of troubleshooting, pick a (X,Y) pair that actually exists in your chart and assign that to your annotation.

Comment: Is it means replace the existing value of my chart with the textannotation value?

Comment: No, it's the opposite. Let's say, for example, your X, in your chart, goes from 0 to 10 and your Y from 0 to 100. Place your annotation at X=5 and Y=50.

Comment: Now it work for me when I put the data point to 0, 0.  May I know how I can know the X  and Y?

Comment: Well, it depends on your layout, i guess... you'll have to pick a coordinate that fits well with all the content you want to show. Also, I'm sure if you search online you may find more detailed documentation about screen coordinates.

Comment: @DerickLoo When you populate your `ColumnSeries` you can keep track of your minX, maxX, minY and maxY. When you end filling the series you could select an approximate pair of values for your `TextAnnotation`.

Comment: @Kirenenko from the above code, mind to guide me where I can get the minX, maxX?  I debug the code and found that the minX, maxX all return me 0

Comment: Inside `for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)` loop

Comment: @Kirenenko it return 0 for minX, maxX